# Run C# console application .NET Framework 4.5.2 in docker

Tags: c#, docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, docker-image

I want to run c# console application .NET Framework 4.5.2 with parameters in docker
can suggest how can i run exe in docker

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own custom Docker image incorporating an (ideally) headless instance of Windows. You will also need to install 4.5.2 to it. [There are images pre-built](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-runtime/), but none seem to target the exact version you want. After building the base image, you'll need to load your console app and have it set to run on container start via the Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks Timothy for response but i am new to docker it would be better if you give some article of full process that how exactly i can start

Comment: @Sahil Sure. Dockerfiles are described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and define the build process for a Docker image. The Dockerfile for Net Framework 4.8 is shown [here](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/1307376c70464589fe766d442446e8a554c2a1b7/src/runtime/4.8/windowsservercore-20H2/Dockerfile).